# C# Class Header Style

Tags: c#, coding-style

I've got a simple style question and would like to know, what's the common pratice.
When deriving from a lot of interfaces, and all these interfaces got long names, it's time for a linebreak in the class header. Should this linebreak be BEFORE or AFTER the colon?

eg.

```
public class DigitalIOConfigurationViewModel
    : SomeLongAbstractClassName, SomeLongInterfaceName, AndAnotherInterface
{...}
```

or

```
public class DigitalIOConfigurationViewModel :
    SomeLongAbstractClassName, SomeLongInterfaceName, AndAnotherInterface
{...}
```

I don't know, if anybody out there cares about little things like this, but i do :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MSDN do it like this

```
public class Control : Component, IDropTarget, 
    ISynchronizeInvoke, IWin32Window, IBindableComponent, IComponent, IDisposable
```

Answer (score 0):

I have mostly seen the second usage (`:` at the end of the type name).

I believe Resharper will indent it this way too.